# How to add / to the end of a URL using IIS7 Rewrite rules

Tags: regex, iis-7

I need to add a trailing / to a url if it doesn't have one or isn't a file. So

> http://www.ddd.com/dasdas

would become

> http://www.ddd.com/dasdas/

But I don't what to just add slash the URl as this will end up with filename like this `style.css/`

So I need a piece of Regex that I can put into the IIS 7 rewrite engeine to append when needed

Answer (score 0):

I am not really familiar with ISS, but if it supports standard regular expressions then I would suggest something like this:

Search pattern: `^.*?\/[\w\d-_]+$`
Replace pattern: `$0\/`